# Travis CI creates two builds for each Github commit push

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, travis-ci

Each time I push to Github, it appears to trigger *two* Travis CI builds - one for the PR and one for the Push itself. They also appear to be separate builds, judging by the links.

What's the exact difference between the two, and how can I enable it so that only one runs?

[image: travis ci build]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can uncheck either building pushes or PRs in the TravisCI settings for the repository: [image: settings SS]

The difference between them is:

- `/pr` builds automerged state (as if you merged the PR and ran the tests on that, note: it won't run if the PR can't be automerged).
- `/push` builds for the current state of the branch you pushed to (as if you ran the tests on your local copy you just pushed),

Comment: you can keep both, but if you would like Travis build on brnahces that are in PRs, you need to configure Travis to skip all non-master branches, see all details at https://github.com/checkstyle/sonar-checkstyle/issues/261

Answer (score 10):

What's happening in your scenario looks like this:

`continuous-integration/travis-ci/push` - only run test on branch

`continuous-integration/travis-ci/pr` - merge and run tests

And this is completely okay - but if you want to get rid of one of the builds you need to disable `Build pushes` or `Build pull requests` in your project settings on Travis.

---

Sources:

https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1504

https://github.com/twisted/twistedchecker/pull/93

https://blog.travis-ci.com/2014-03-05-repository-settings/